# How to not pass an empty string with local storage

Tags: javascript

I have set up local storage to pass two form inputs from a form on page A to a form on page B. This works fine... but if I navigate to page B without inputting anything in page A, or navigate directly to page B, the form inputs are blank. How do I get local storage to pass variables only if there is a variable to pass?

Thanks for any help!

Here's the code I have so far:
Page A.

```
    function pageSel() {
      var parseAmount = document.getElementById("stepperAmount").value;
      var parseMonth = document.getElementById("stepperMonth").value;
      localStorage.setItem("amountKey", parseAmount);
      localStorage.setItem("monthKey", parseMonth); 
   }
```

Page B.

```
    function pageSel2() {
        var parseAmount2 = localStorage.getItem("amountKey");
        var parseMonth2 = localStorage.getItem("monthKey");
        document.getElementById("demo1").value = parseAmount2;
        document.getElementById("demo2").value = parseMonth2;
    }

    function roundAmount() {
        var x=document.getElementById("demo1"); 
        x.value=Math.round(x.value/250)*250;
    }

    function roundMonth() {
        var x=document.getElementById("demo2"); 
        x.value=Math.round(x.value/12)*12;
    }

   pageSel2();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is struggling with this, I've come up with a solution:

The Page A code is fine as it is.
Page B is now:

```
function pageSel2() {
        var parseAmount2 = localStorage.getItem("amountKey");
        var parseMonth2 = localStorage.getItem("monthKey");
        document.getElementById("demo1").value = parseAmount2 ? parseAmount: 1000;
        document.getElementById("demo2").value = parseMonth2 ? parseAmount: 36;
    }

    function roundAmount() {
        var x=document.getElementById("demo1"); 
        x.value=Math.round(x.value/250)*250;
    }

    function roundMonth() {
        var x=document.getElementById("demo2"); 
        x.value=Math.round(x.value/12)*12;
    }

   pageSel2();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if a value is present before setting localStorage:

```
function pageSel() {
  var parseAmount = document.getElementById("stepperAmount").value;
  var parseMonth = document.getElementById("stepperMonth").value;
  if (parseAmount) {
    localStorage.setItem("amountKey", parseAmount);
  }
  if (parseMonth) {
    localStorage.setItem("monthKey", parseMonth);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this doesn't have any effect. I think I should add that when navigating directly to page B, the default values are displayed for a second and then they appear to be overwritten with blank data.